# Spyder IDE Console History

Tags: python, spyder

How to see print history in console in spyder IDE ? If more data gets printed it does not shows on console and not even shows the scroll bar.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Please provide a working example that shows your problem, and a screenshot to understand it better.

Answer (score 19):

The default configuration is to buffer 10,000 lines. If you require a larger buffer, you will have to change settings in `Preferences`->`Console`->`Display`->`Source Code`->`Buffer:` to increase the number of lines.

[image]

Comment: But I cannot see any scroll bar,so I can't see all the data.

Comment: When you right-click on the console window, you have an option: `Save history log..`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Windows 7 . Only the last part can be seen. not the whole history.

Comment: Does increasing the buffer lines to 20,000 lines, show you at least **more of the last part** (if not the whole history)? Then you should increment the buffer further to suit your requirement.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @kums is right, you need to increase your buffer size first, then open a new console and run your script again. That's because changes to our preferences only take effect on new consoles. It's also worth mentioning that you need to be careful with the amount of lines you want to see in the console. `2000` is perhaps the highest number advisable. We decreased that number from `10000` to `500` in Spyder version 2.3 because if you print an infinite loop, then the whole application will be blocked with the huge amount of text to be printed.

Answer (score 11):

This is an update for Spyder version 3.1.4:

1. *Tools*
2. *Preferences* (The shortcut is: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P)
3. *IPython console* (in the left menu of the Preferences utility)
4. Source code

   5. Buffer: ***500*** Lines (in the right menu under the "Display" tab)

Increase the buffer to view more lines in the IPython console. Then close and restart Spyder.

Comment: Do you know if the history is written to a file too?

Comment: Yes, on Linux, running spyder for Python3, it text history is saved at `${HOME}/.config/spyder-py3/history.py`, whereas an `sqlite` history file is also saved in the same directory, directly from the ipython console. I'm running Spyder 5.1.1.

Comment: @user3731622 See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627152/13993139