# How to see the console history of all commands in the IPython console in Spyder

Tags: console, stack, ipython, spyder

In my IPython console in Spyder I can see only the latest executed commands -- as the former disappear from the console window.

I wonder if there is some way --e.g. by adjusting some parameter-- to see the console history of all commands in the IPython console in Spyder.

Could you help me?  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you type `%quickref` in the Ipython console you'll see one section that looks like this:

```
History:

_i, _ii, _iii    : Previous, next previous, next next previous input
_i4, _ih[2:5]    : Input history line 4, lines 2-4
exec _i81        : Execute input history line #81 again
%rep 81          : Edit input history line #81
_, __, ___       : previous, next previous, next next previous output
_dh              : Directory history
_oh              : Output history
%hist            : Command history of current session.
%hist -g foo     : Search command history of (almost) all sessions for 'foo'.
%hist -g         : Command history of (almost) all sessions.
%hist 1/2-8      : Command history containing lines 2-8 of session 1.
%hist 1/ ~2/     : Command history of session 1 and 2 sessions before current.
%hist ~8/1-~6/5  : Command history from line 1 of 8 sessions ago to
                   line 5 of 6 sessions ago.
%edit 0/         : Open editor to execute code with history of current session.
```

One of those commands should do what you want...

Comment: %hist is the answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I had same/similar issue - computer rebooted and lost unsaved code in spyder (i didn't user ipython)

found the history file at:

```
"C:\Users\my_username\.spyder-py3\history.py"
```

(If you have a different version, look for `.spyderXXXXXX`)

`hist -g` may only show a limited number of lines - maybe because of [console print limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history). If you compare the result of `hist -g` to that of `hist -g some_word` (eg `hist -g import`). You'll see `hist -g import` shows some earlier lines than `hist -g`. This indicates `hist` shows a limited number of lines.