# Accessing the spyder history log

Tags: python, spyder, history

In spyder I often look back for code I wrote in the past, via the command :

`%hist -g print` if I want to see my print statements.

But recently most of my history disappeared and I only have access to codes I wrote in the last days.

I would like to manually access the history log, and have seen from multiple sources  that it should be stored in a file 'history.py'. (e.g [How to see the console history of all commands in the IPython console in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041899/how-to-see-the-console-history-of-all-commands-in-the-ipython-console-in-spyder)).

I've gone through all the 'history.py'  files I have and at most they define a class History but don't contain the actual codelines that I wrote in the past.

So my question is : Which file contains the history itself and how do I access it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder's history is available at

`~/.spyder-py3/history.py`

where `~` stands for your Users directory on macOS and Windows.

On a modern Linux distro this file is located at

`~/.config/spyder-py3/history.py`

Comment: What about the history tab that was available next to the IPython console? I'm using Spyder 4.

Comment: @Zizzipupp : `Ctrl + Shift + L` should open the history tab pane