# spyder Ipython console buffer

Tags: ipython, buffer, spyder

I'm using Spyder 3.5 and trying to change the number of IPython Console buffer line. The default is 500 lines. But no matter what number I change to, the limit is still 500, and I cannot scroll back beyond 500 lines. I also open a new console after changing the preference but it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

[image: Screenshot of my setting in Preferences]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spyder IDE Console History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change your settings in the IPython console rubric (Tools->Preferences->IPython console). Also make sure to reload spyder or open a new Ipython console for the changes to take effect.

[image: Settings of Spyder]

Comment: Restarting Python is vital for changes to take the effect - I have just realised that. :)