# The output in the console window not being shown

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Spyder in Python, and my output is probably 4000 lines, and the code runs fine without any errors, and while the code is running i can even see the output being produced. 
It takes like 2 seconds to produce the output, but only the last 100 lines I guess are being shown in the output.
 The rest of the output just disappeared. 
It's seem there is a page limit or something associated with Spyder, so it only shows the last 100 lines or some number of lines.

How do I see my entire output?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spyder IDE Console History](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history)

Comment: I just tried what is on that link, and it didn't work. The output lines are still limited to what I had before. Also I am using windows 7,8, and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to print out the text to a document, later you can refer to it. You won't miss, even a single line.

Comment: yea that is the plan, but for now I just want to see that output and make sure it is following the pattern I want it to before I spend anymore time trying to code it further.

Comment: try running the script on python idle, i think this will print all lines for you

Comment: I am just outputting to another document. I mean either way I just want to make sure that the output is correct. It is gonna be hard to read either way. But, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring back console by following steps -

1. Go to View -> Panes
2. Panes menu will show you list of options
3. Select 'IPython Console'
4. Try running some print statement, you will be able to see output in console.

Keyboard shortcut for doing same is - Ctrl+ Shift+ I