# Too many lines in the Python console

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem, where my Python code are generating some data I need for Machine Learning. But it generates more data than my console can handle, so the first lines are missing when the code is done running. 
Can I somehow, while the code is running, transfer the data to word, excel or similar program?

I have tried running the code in Spyder 3.7 and Python 3.8.

The code I am using:

```
from itertools import combinations 

comb = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50], 5) 

for i in list(comb): 
    print (i)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `python script.py > output.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spyder IDE Console History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751140/spyder-ide-console-history)